# RStudio freaks when str.class enters browser()

Tags: r, rstudio

Looks like RStudio freaks when a custom class object is created with custom `str` method.
Once entered into `str` method debugging with `browser()` there is no response from any of the calls.
Below may help to reproduce:

```
as.abc = function(x) structure(x, class="abc")
str.abc = function(x, ...) browser()
package.skeleton()
devtools::load_all("anRpackage")
a = as.abc(1L)
str(a)
Browse[1]> ls()
Browse[1]> 1+1
```

Is there any specific way I should use `browser()` and str methods in RStudio?
This is not happening in R console.

Comment: Seems like a question for the folks at RStudio.

Comment: RStudio calls `str()` on all objects to populate the environment pane; this is triggering the `browser()` call in your `str.abc()` method definition. This could probably be fixed / worked around in RStudio, but calling `browser()` in `str()` is probably a bad way to go.

Comment: @KevinUshey this was my guess. This is very good idea when developing new `str` method :) Could you fill a ticket on RStudio support? so at least it will be a known issues. hmm.. RStudio could force `str.default` which should be safe and often more desired for RStudio application than some user's custom method which may produce anything.